# Windows 2012 R2 DNS SERVFAIL on linux / mac clients

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, nslookup, resolv.conf, windows-dns

SERVFAIL is causing issues with some of our applications on linux/macs. I presume this is Windows DNS causing some problems with our linux/mac clients? Then again Windows clients are able to do shortname lookup without any issue.

From a Mac/Centos 7.3 host

```
[root@user-vm ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf 

domain example.org
search example.org c.example.org
nameserver 10.1.1.71
nameserver 10.1.1.70
nameserver 10.3.20.71
nameserver 10.3.20.70

[root@user-vm ~]# nslookup 123
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 10.1.1.71, trying next server
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 10.1.1.70, trying next server
Server:     10.3.20.71
Address:    10.3.20.71#53

** server can't find 123: SERVFAIL

[root@user-vm ~]# nslookup 123.example.org.
Server:     10.1.1.71
Address:    10.1.1.71#53

** server can't find 123.example.org.: NXDOMAIN
```

From a Windows client

```
C:\Users\user>nslookup 123
Server:  pdc01.example.org
Address:  10.1.1.70

*** pdc01.example.org can't find 123: Non-existent domain
```